# Optimize repeated expensive computations in Rxjs given an Observable of Array

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, observable

Given the following script:

```js
type Data = {
  id: string
  value: number
}

// This is a pure function: given val, res will always be the same
const veryExpensiveCalc = (val: number) => {
  const res = // ... 5 seconds of sync computation ...
  return res
}

const array$ = new ReplaySubject<Array<Data>>(1)

const allComputedValues$ = array$.pipe(
  map(arr =>
    arr.map(item =>
      // I want this veryExpensiveCalc to be performed only when
      // item.value changes for this item.id, or the item was not
      // there before
      veryExpensiveCalc(item.value)
    )
  )
)

allComputedValues$
  .pipe(
    tap(newStruct => {
      console.log('newStruct', newStruct)
    })
  )
  .subscribe()
```

I'd like to optimize how `allComputedValues$` is calculated. In particular let's say that an item is added or removed to `array$`, or the order of the elements change: then `veryExpensiveCalc` is executed again on every item of the array, even though that's not needed at all. I just need `allComputedValues$` from the previous computation with the result of `veryExpensiveCalc` applied only to the newly added element (in case of addition).

What's the best way to write this in a functional reactive fashion? It should work also if there are multiple elements edited/added/removed at the same time (so that `veryExpensiveCalc` is executed only on the elements that have a different `value` given the same `id`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use the `scan()` operator here:

```js
const allComputedValues$ = array$.pipe(
  scan(
    (acc, crtArr) => {
      // with these we 'automatically' remove the current items(from `acc`) whose ids are not in the current array
      const newIds = {};
      const newValues = {};

      crtArr.forEach(crt => {
        const { id: currentId, value: crtValue } = crt;

        // if new or edited
        if (!acc.ids[currentId] || acc.values[currentId] !== crtValue) {
          newIds[currentId] = true;
          newValues[currentId] = veryExpensiveCalc(crtValue);
        }
      });

      return { ids: newIds, values: newValues };
    },
    { ids: {}, values: {} },
  ),
)
```

Comment: That's a very nice solution! :) I completely forgot about the scan operator!

Comment: I’m glad I could help!